# How to make the Loss of pay based on hours in Odoo 8

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8, qweb

I am currently working on payslip customization of odoo erp. Here is a problem i am facing with Half Day Loss of Pay.

I added an "unpaid leave" leave type and applied for an unpaid leave. Then the odoo calculate the leave as one day loss of pay from the salary and it is working fine. While we apply for the unpaid leave we can see that the time period of the leave is 9.00 to 18.00.

My requirement is, if I need a half day leave means, I can choose 9.00 to 13.00 [4 hours] on the time period. But if I choose so, the odoo is considering that as one day [8 hours] loss of pay.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue and make the loss of pay as per hours we are giving.

Comment: As far as i know, Odoo can only calculate in terms of full days. Even requesting a leave from monday till sunday (premise: saturday and sunday aren't workdays) will calculate 7 days. But you can always change the "days" field manually.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I am new in this odoo. I am stuck with this.

Comment: Maybe this will help a bit: [OCA hr Addons](https://github.com/OCA/hr/tree/8.0)